# How to write some script src <script src=""> in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I write a php code. In this code I must use two different script scr

```
<script src="js/calendar/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" ></script>           
<script src="js/calendar/persianDatepicker.js"></script>`
```

for a persianDatepicker and another one

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

for use with ajax.

When I have

`jquery-1.10.1.min.js` before
`jquery.min.js`,

datapicker have this error

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).persianDatepicker is not a function`

and when I have

`jquery.min.js` before
`jquery-1.10.1.min.js`

I see this error of ajax

`jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/zahra/Desktop/khabarone/server.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

So, What I must do???
How can I use these two scripts?

Comment: Don't, just use one. The first should handle both. Also you cannot load a file from harddisk (protocol file:///) with AJAX

Comment: your question is unclear. Datepicker always use at client side , why use ajax? ,what is difference between `jquery.min.js` and `jquery-1.10.1.min.js`?

Comment: PS: I do not see any reason to use both since `jquery-1.10.1.min.js` can handle the Ajax just fine -  but if you must, see the duplicate

Comment: @mplungjan , i use `url: server.php` in ajax, is wrong? how can i do that? server is a local file in my folder.

Comment: @MohsenShakibafar, i use `jquery-1.10.1.min.js` for datapicker and use 'jquery.min.js' for ajax. if i delete each one, that part have error.

Comment: Then you are loading the page from the harddisk instead of localhost and jquery-1.10.1.min.js can handle any ajax as long as you access a SERVER and not a file:/// - Please DELETE `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>` from your page and make sure the other jQuery is before you need it. Post more of your HTML if there is still an issue

Comment: @mplungjan, thank you